# Why won't react wait for my fetch call too finish?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I'm making a fetch call in componentDidMount of a component to update the model of the webapp (profile information). On first render or refesh the model is empty. If I switch to another scene then back, the model is working as expected.

The Tutorstore model is just a export that holds data and methods for working with that data. It is passed via props to any component that needs to work with it. The fetch call is the Tutorstore.Fetch method.

Component making the call

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
      let tID = sessionStorage.getItem("Tutor");
      await this.props.tutorStore.Fetch(tID);
      let qDB = new PouchDB(
        "https://b705ce6d-2856-466b-b76e-7ebd39bf5225-bluemix.cloudant.com/programs"
      );
      qDB
        .changes({ since: "now", live: true, include_docs: true })
        .on("change", () => {
          this.props.tutorStore.Fetch(tID);
        });

      console.log(this.props.tutorStore.Tutor._id);
    };
```

Model export

```
export let TutorStore = observable({
  Tutor: {},
  Queue: [],
  QLength: null
});
```

Actual fetch method in model

```
TutorStore.Fetch = id => {
  var db = new PouchDB(
    "https://b705ce6d-2856-466b-b76e-7ebd39bf5225-bluemix.cloudant.com/tutors"
  );
  var qDB = new PouchDB(
    "https://b705ce6d-2856-466b-b76e-7ebd39bf5225-bluemix.cloudant.com/programs"
  );

  db.get(id)
    .then(function(doc) {
      if (!doc.isLoggedIn) {
        doc.isLoggedIn = true;
        db.put(doc);
      }
      TutorStore.Tutor = doc;
      console.log(TutorStore.Tutor);
    })
    .then(() => {
      qDB.get(TutorStore.Tutor.programID).then(function(doc) {
        TutorStore.Queue = doc.activeQ;
        TutorStore.QLength = doc.qLength;
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

The prop chain exists, no problem there. A console log from the model shows that the fetch call worked and updated the model, but it doesn't show up in the component.

So again the problem is my model fetch is undefined on first render. It did work, I just can't get react to wait for it on the initial render. Switching scenes loads the the appropriate data from the model.

I've tried putting it the fetch call into a promise constructor with no luck (do that for other db operations in this app and it works).

Comment: I see `fetch` used/called several times in the code shared, is there a specific one that isn't working as expected? Please be more explicit what the issue is, and what the repro steps are. Please also include all code relevant to issue, i.e. you mention some modal component code isn't functioning as expected, please include it. [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Like @DrewReese mentioned above it would've been very useful if you could add more details. With that said I do see some problems here. I'd start by using `async` & `await` syntax for `Fetch` function (some IDE-s should be able to do that automatically) or returning the promise from it other wise it will simple run asynchronously.

Comment: Hey updated my post with some more information. 

The repro is that when I load the page that should show profile (tutor) information, its empty because the model is undefined. I'm using scene based rendering on this component, and if I switch to a different scene and then back, the information is there and the model is defined as expected. 

I'm using pouchDB's api to fetch info from a database and fill the model.

Comment: You need to return it `db.get(id)`. Thats a promise.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy return the retrieve information then assign it? Or just return the ```Tutorstore.Tutor = doc;```

Comment: @NLand `return db.get(id).......` By the way you have 2 promises,  `db.get(id)` and `qDB.get(T` return them both in their own context or just await the both.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that doesn't seem to work, same behaviour. Tried returning the entire chain and tried returning the individual doc and assigning it outside of that